# Internet Explorer 8: How to make read only text input have no cursor

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am trying to simulate the look and feel of a Firefox disabled text input: textarea and input text.

The only browser compatibility I have to worry about is Internet Explorer 8.  I do NOT have to worry about anything earlier (Intranet)

Internet Explorer does not allow one to change the text color of a disabled test input.  It does allow background color to be changed but gray text on a gray background color was beyond illegible.

I have an input box and text area declared as follows:

```
<input name="Count" id="Count" onfocus="this.blur()" type="text" readOnly="readonly" value="0"/>
<textarea name="Notes" id="Notes" style="width: 100%;" onfocus="this.blur()" rows="10" cols="20" readOnly="readonly"/>
```

I have the following styles applied through a CSS:

```
input[readonly], textarea[readonly] {
  color:black !important;
  background-color: threedface !important;
}
```

Visually, this works excellently in both Firefox and IE.  However, IE still allows a cursor into the text area or text box.  What am I missing?

**ADDITION**

By cursor, I am referring to a keyboard cursor such as when you are typing a reply here.

Maybe my problem is better stated as a user can still click on the text area and have a keyboard cursor show up.  It appears that the blinking cursor disappears quickly though.

Comment: I dont see the problem in my IE8  http://jsfiddle.net/dSxQ7/

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference with this code in IE 8, IE 9, or Chrome.  They all seem to show the cursor when you first click in the field, then it disappears.

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue on my IE8. No blinking cursor appears.

Comment: To Shawn: that is the behavior I am hoping to fix if possible.  If possible, I do not want the cursor to show up even for that split second.  Firefox doesn't show the cursor at all.

Answer (score 3):

try adding a cursor property to your css

```
input[readonly], textarea[readonly] {
  color:black !important;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: threedface !important;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=default

--- 12/01/27

Revisiting this solution, I found the following to work for me, hopefully its helpful to you as well:

Comment: by cursor, I meant keyboard cursor(added edit to original question)  The mouse cursor doesn't change using the style I originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple jQuery function in script tag for all readonly input fields.
You can even use any specific ID or Class if you need for a particular item only.

```
$('input[readonly]').focus(function(){
this.select();
});
```

Comment: As this is you first answer a little advice:  An answer consisting entirely of code is rarely sufficient, ie its not clear for the answer if this is a correction, additional code, where its supposed to go etc.  I;m not saying you need to be verbose but 'Add this call to x... which causes y'

Answer (score -1):

Can you use `disabled=disabled` instead of `readonly=readonly`?

Comment: `disabled` will not submit input.